# Fileinfo: MIME-Type AND Description

Tags: php

I'm using fileinfo to get MIME-Types and description.
At the moment I create two finfo Objects, like this:

```
$x = new finfo(FILEINFO_NONE, ....);
print $x->file($filename);
print '\n';
$x = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME, ....);
print $x->file($filename);
```

This results in something like this:

```
application/pdf; charset=binary
PDF document, version 1.2
```

It works fine for me, but is there a way to get description and mime info in one call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, is really simple, i don't know how i could not have seen this earlier:
For the method "file", there is a second optional argument, like this:

```
$x = new finfo(FILEINFO_NONE, ....);
print $x->file($filename);
print '\n';
print $x->file($filename, FILEINFO_MIME);
```

Comment: But I thought you were looking to get all the info "in one call".

Comment: Sorry, this is really too long ago to know why or how this made sense to me. Past-me is even dumber than present-me.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but the documentation states that the first parameter of `finfo_open()` accepts "one or disjunction of more Fileinfo constants", which means that we should be able to `OR` a couple constants together:

```
$x = new finfo(FILEINFO_NONE | FILEINFO_MIME, ...);
```

Comment: Already tried that, but as FILEINFO_NONE is 0 (zero), FILEINFO_NONE | FILEINFO_MIME equals FILEINFO_MIME.

Comment: @JohnSmith, Ah crap!  In that case, I don't think it is possible to do it all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert to the old values, without charsets, PHP 5.3 introduced the FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE constant. Switching from FILEINFO_MIME to FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE

```
 if( class_exists('finfo')&&defined('FILEINFO_MIME'))
   {
       $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
       return $finfo->file($_FILE['tempname']);

   }
```

for example for php_file return:
text/x-php; charset=utf-8

but following code:

```
if( class_exists('finfo')&&defined('FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE'))
   {
       $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
       return $finfo->file($_FILE['tempname']);

   }
```

for php_file return:
text/x-php

see following link:
http://debugsober.com/blog/PHP-53-Fileinfo-and-weird-mime_type-charsets

Comment: That doesn't return the description.